# Unexpected character '​' Error when Compiling

Tags: c#, wpf

My company is using 3rd party WPF control called syntaxEditor from Actipro
I'm trying to save from the control using saveFileDialog

```
       public void saveascommand()
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlgs = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        dlgs.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
        dlgs.DefaultExt = ".text"; // Default file extension
        dlgs.Filter = "C# (.cs)|*.cs|VB.NET (.vb)|*.vb|HTML (.html)|*.html|JavaScript (.js)|*.js|XML (.xml)|*.xml|XAML (.xaml)|*.xaml|SQL (.sql)|*.sql"; // Filter files by extension
        Nullable<bool> result = dlgs.ShowDialog();
        if (result == true)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(dlgs.FileName, string.Empty);
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(dlgs.FileName))
            {
                ​syntaxEditor.Document.SaveFile(dlgs.FileName, LineTerminator.CarriageReturnNewline);//The code from ActiPro Documentation
                filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dlgs.FileName);
                filepath = dlgs.FileName;
                savedfirsttime = true;
                Title = "ProCode | " + filename;
            }
        }


    }
```

when compiling, I get this error CS1056

Comment: Where exactly do you get this error? Which " is the error talking about?

Comment: ​syntaxEditor.Document.SaveFile(dlgs.FileName, LineTerminator.CarriageReturnNewline);

Comment: Did you *copy* that line from the documentation? Sometimes documentation has characters, that the compiler complains about (for example, they use different quotation marks on the web than what your compiler expects, or have non-breaking spaces instead of real spaces). Just delete the whole line an type it by hand. Something you copied from the documentation is making your compiler unhappy.

Comment: Likely the error is not int the `.SaveFile` line. And very likely you copy-pasted from outlook/word and instead `"` you got into your code file one of those fancy word double quotes instead.

Comment: Yeah I copied it from documentation.